# Instant real-time notifications in React

Tags: reactjs, notifications, local-storage, real-time

I'm currently working on a React Application based on the MERN stack, and I have a use case where I would like to implement instant notifications within the application.

For example, I'm having a shopping cart, where the items in it are added to the `localstorage` when the user "`adds to the cart`" and fetched from the `localstorage` and shown to the user when they need to view it. What I need to achieve is, displaying a badge (as shown in the image) containing the amount of items in the cart.

As per my research I have found that it is impossible to watch and trigger events related to localstorage within the same tab, which means that is not the ideal solution. I need to update the badge as soon as the user adds to the cart.

What will be my best options for this use case? Is there a convenient way to implement real time notifications in React?

(Note that this badge is on the header which is a separate component, and the '`add to cart`' is in another component.)

[image]

Comment: You want to persist the data in the frontend. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JothamArdel, yes. I am not planning to persist data into a database, the data is only being persisted into the localstorage and fetched from there onwards.

Comment: Do you already have the badge component in place in your application?

Comment: @JothamArdel, yes. It is a separate component.

Comment: You could have items of the carts in an array, get the number using the length property and update it to the state, since you're already  saving it to the local storage and you're able to retrieve it back.

Comment: Cool, are you suggesting to use a useEffect to update the state when the array changes?

Comment: useEffect works like the lifecycle methods you can read up more on useEffect, useState and lifecycle methods in the react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. Rather useState in situations you are using a functional component or use a class based components to render the component and update the state.

Comment: @JothamArdel, since I'm using functional components, I will be using useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these: functional component where you leverage on the useState Hook or use the class based component. In this example I am levering a package 'local-storage' to get the saved items in the local storage.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import ls from 'local-storage';

const Cart = () => {
    const [numberOfCart, setNumberOfCart] = useState(0);
    setNumberOfCart(ls.get('cart').length);
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{numberOfCart}</span>
    </div>
  )

}


class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      numberOfCart: 0
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ numberOfCart: ls('get').length })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.numberOfCart}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, I will apply this to my use case and update you if required!